# MongoDB check length when using embedded documents for _id index

Tags: mongodb

I'm using an embedded document for `_id` in my application, eg:

```
> db.entities.findOne({}, {_id: 1})
{ "_id" : { "id" : "...", "type": "...", "servicePath" : "..." } }
```

Sometimes, when the combined length of sub-fields `id`, `type` and `servicePath` is too large, I get this kind of error when trying to insert a document:

```
Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing orion.entities.$_id_ 1086
```

which is fine, as MongoDB have a [index key limit of 1024 bytes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) (and `_id` is compulsory index):

> The total size of an index entry, which can include structural overhead depending on the BSON type, must be less than 1024 bytes.

However, I would like to set a check in my program to prevent in advance this error. I mean, to check that this condition doesn't occur:

```
length(id) + length(type) + length(servicePath) + structural overhead > 1024
```

How to know the "structural overhead" in this case? Is it constant or would it depend on the particular id/type/servicePath?